# Selecting the following sibling of a sorted node

Tags: xslt, xpath

Trying to work out how to select the following-sibling of an XSLT node when the node has been sorted in XSLT 1.0. I've searched but can't find anything for sorted nodes, as it only selects the sibling of the *unsorted* node.

**Data**

```
<data>
    <number order='4'>Four</number>
    <number order='1'>One</number>
    <number order='3'>Three</number>
    <number order='2'>Two</number>
</data>
```

**Code**

```
<xsl:for-each select="/data/number">
    <xsl:sort select="@order"/>
    <xsl:if test="position() mod 2 = 1">
        <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
        <xsl:text> - </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::*/text()"/>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

**Expected output**

```
One - Two
Three - Four
```

**Actual Output**

```
One - Three
Three - Two
```

Comment: Can try using number(position()) mod 2 = 1 inside the test. Because position() will return a string.im not sure whether it will work just give a try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you sort a sequence of nodes, you get the same nodes in a new sequence. Because they are the same nodes, they have the same siblings that they always had. If you copy the nodes to a result tree, then the copies will have new siblings, but that's because of the action of writing them to a result tree, not because of the sorting action.

Another way of putting this: you are processing a sequence of nodes that aren't siblings, so you can't use following-sibling to get the next node in the sequence.

Processing a sorted sequence of nodes becomes much easier in XSLT 2.0, which allows such a sequence to be bound to a variable. XSLT 1.0 only has node-sets, so sequences of nodes in a particular order can only exist transiently.

But in this particular case, it seems easy enough to do

```
<xsl:value-of select="."/>
<xsl:if test="position() mod 2 = 1">
    <xsl:text> - </xsl:text>
</xsl:if>
```

Comment: Thanks. The actual problem I had wasn't solved by the solution here, but you did answer my question about whether what I was trying was possible. I'm marking this as the accepted answer as it answers the question I asked best.

Answer (score 1):

> it only selects the sibling of the unsorted node.

That is correct. Why don't you do simply:

```
<xsl:for-each select="/data/number">
    <xsl:sort select="@order"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="position() mod 2 = 1">
            <xsl:text>-</xsl:text>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:for-each>
```

---

Note that the default sort data-type is `text`; you probably want to make it:

```
<xsl:sort select="@order" data-type="number"/>
```

Comment: This works for my simplified example, but the actual place I'm trying to use this code is a html table which won't work with the table row tags being split up. 

So is it simply not possible to get the sibling of a sorted node in XSLT 1.0?

Comment: If you truly need them to be siblings, you must copy them (or otherwise recreate them as new nodes) into a variable first. And in XSLT 1.0 you will also need to convert that variable into a node-set before you can process it further.